# Can GraphQL operations/results format be simplified?

Tags: graphql, postgraphile

I'm using latest version of Postraphile (on its Docker container) and I've installed `pg-simplify-inflector` plugin, I've noted an improvement respect to names for operations, and I wish to get a simplified format for operations and their results. Example:

For this operation:

```
query MyQuery {
  iddocTypes {
    nodes {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

with result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "iddocTypes": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "some 1"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "some 2"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "some 3"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I wish to get this:

```
query MyQuery {
  iddocTypes {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

with result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "iddocTypes": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "some 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "some 2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "some 3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm using these options for Postgraphile in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
      "--dynamic-json",
      "--subscriptions",
      "--no-setof-functions-contain-nulls",
      "--no-ignore-rbac",
      "--no-ignore-indexes",
      "--show-error-stack", "json",
      "--extended-errors", "hint,detail,errcode",
      "--enable-query-batching",
      "--legacy-relations", "omit",
      "--append-plugins", "@graphile-contrib/pg-simplify-inflector",
      "--enhance-graphiql"
```

What do I need to do to simplify it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to rewrite the data in the client once it has been received? The answer to your question is "you can't".

Comment: I asked this question because [Hasura](https://hasura.io) works with these formats, so I thought maybe it is related to configuration or some plugin, etc.

Comment: [looking simpler] arrays vs pagination => overfetching vs good practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this option:

```
      "--simple-collections", "only",
```

Source: https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/usage-cli/